# Cutom Elements: Can't extend from button Illegal constructor

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

```
<my-button 
        id="elem" 
        >
        problem
       </my-button>


       <button>
        works
       </button>

class MyButton extends HTMLButtonElement  {
    constructor(){
        super(); // must call constructor from parent class
    }
}

  customElements.define("my-button", MyButton, { extends: 'button'});
```

My question is : why I didn't get my element like Button ? Just text

Comment: Sounds like you're after `<button is="my-button"`.

Comment: FYI Apple has stated they will never support _customized built-in elements_ in Safari

Answer (score 1):

Note: *Customized Built-In Elements* do **not** work in Apple-Safari
And never will, [here is Apples POV going back to **2013**](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2013OctDec/0801.html) (yes, Web Components are not a new fad)

*Customized Built-In Elements* notation is the original Element with an **is=** reference:
`<button is="my-button">`

Code below works in Chrome, Edge, FireFox and Opera

```html
<button is="my-button" id="foo">Click Me!</button>
<button is="my-button" id="bar">Click Me!</button>

<script>
customElements.define("my-button", 
  class extends HTMLButtonElement  {
      connectedCallback(){
        console.log("connected", this.id);
        this.onclick = evt => console.log("You clicked", this.id);
      }
  }, { extends: 'button'});
 </script>
```

##### createElement notation:

`let myButton = document.createElement("button", { is: "my-button" });`

##### General advice

Stick to *Autonomous Elements* (extending from `HTMLElement`)

```html
<my-button id="foo">Click Me!</my-button>
<my-button id="bar">Click Me!</my-button>
```

(create the `my-button` yourself)